# Does 3ware 9550SX SATA RAID controller work with WD 2TB caviar black edition drives?

Tags: hardware-raid

I have 4-years old 3ware 9550SX SATA RAID and i want to upgrade drives to 2TB.
Official LSI  HCL says that they support only enterprise-level disks and the latest HCL speaks only about 1TB drives. Does anyone have some  experience with 3ware 9550SX SATA RAID and WD caviar black edition 2TB drives?

TIA, Vitaly

Answer (score 2):

The firmware on non RE drives has a poor TLER (google it)  They will work but under heavy io the array will most likely become degraded and rebuild constantly.

Just read up on TLER and raid.

Comment: +1 Work, probably yes. Work well, probably no.